# pattern lock in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I need to make a pattern lock for my application. The example I am following is from here: http://blog.grio.com/2011/11/android-pattern-lock-on-iphone.html

However it is a full screen lock. I need the pattern lock to appear in only a part of the screen, as my screen needs to have text fields and buttons as well. I have changed some coordinates in it and have brought the pattern down to one fourth of its size.

The code given in the example uses `presentModalViewController:animated:` which means that the view shall be presented full screen. What should be done so that the view is NOT presented full screen? Also when I am porting the code to a new project with storyboards, I am getting the exception `NSInvalidArgument:` unrecognized selector sent to instance

DrawPattern:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawrect...");

    if (!_trackPointValue)
        return;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

    CGPoint from;
    UIView *lastDot;
    for (UIView *dotView in _dotViews) {
        from = dotView.center;
        NSLog(@"drwaing dotview: %@", dotView);
        NSLog(@"\tdrawing from: %f, %f", from.x, from.y);

        if (!lastDot)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
        else
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);

        lastDot = dotView;
    }

    CGPoint pt = [_trackPointValue CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"\t to: pt = %f, pt = %f", pt.x, pt.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pt.x, pt.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);

    _trackPointValue = nil;
}


- (void)clearDotViews {
    [_dotViews removeAllObjects];
}


- (void)addDotView:(UIView *)view {
    if (!_dotViews)
        _dotViews = [NSMutableArray array];

    [_dotViews addObject:view];
}


- (void)drawLineFromLastDotTo:(CGPoint)pt {
    _trackPointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return NO;
}


- (void)lockEntered:(NSString*)key {
    NSLog(@"key: %@", key);

    if (![key isEqualToString:@"020508"]) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Wrong pattern!"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)lockClicked:(id)sender {
    DrawPatternViewController *lockVC = [[DrawPatternViewController alloc] init];
    [lockVC setTarget:self withAction:@selector(lockEntered:)];
    [self presentModalViewController:lockVC animated:YES];
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your 'lock view' as a sub view of the view with the other text fields and migrate the controlling code to the view controller that is controlling that view. Then you won't have a view controller which needs to be pushed.

Technically you could instead add the 'lock vies's view controller as a child view controller (better for future reuse). In this case the 'lock view' is still added as a sub view of the view with the other text fields.

Comment: I removed the initial view controller and just typed the portion in the button click method in the viewDidLoad method of the DrawPatternViewController. Also I took those methods from DrawLockPatterView(UIView class) responsible for drawing the 3x3 grid and pasted it to DrawPatternViewController. That enabled me to add text fields to the same view as the pattern lock. But I was told by my superiors that this was not acceptable. I'm trying to follow your approach now. But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Should I be using addChildViewController?

Comment: Your superior told you it wasn't acceptable but didn't offer guidance? You still need a UIView subclass if you're using drawRect: and that subclass should be handled like the text fields - added as a subview and configured within the controller. Using a child view controller allows you to keep the lock management separate to the place where it's being used (hence better for reuse).